# WP8.1 transparent gradient

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, transparency, linear-gradients

if I use the linear gradient this way in WP 8.1:

```
<Grid Height="20">
  <Grid.Background>
     <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
     </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

I get a picture like this:

[image: linear Gradient]

When I understand it right, this is due to a deficient in alpha value transition. For Windows XAML there are *MarkupExtensions*, that fix this issue, however for WindowsPhone I cannot use *MarkupExtensions*.

Is there another solid workaround, that satisfies my needs for this?

(and yes, it should be transparent, as it should fade out a `Scrollbar` on the Bottom and this `Scrollbar` has content of different colors. Usually I can just trick around by making the "transparent" color just the color of the surrounding.)

Comment: What exacly do you want to achieve and what's the problem with the current output? As far as I can see, it does exactly what your code says.

Comment: the background in attached image is black. It might be a bad example to go from black to transparent on a black background, but I put it there intentionally to show the problem more obvious (it should be all black). So no it does not at all what I want it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I guess the problem is the white color...?

The problem is that `Transparent` is the same as `#FFFFFF` with full transparency, so in ARGB notation `#00FFFFFF`. What you want is a fully transparent `#000000`, so in ARGB notation this is `#00000000`.

Using ARGB notation, I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
<Grid Height="20">
  <Grid.Background>
     <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#ff000000" Offset="1"/>
     </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for. And this method is simpler than expected.